# Find files with spaces in the bash

Tags: bash, find

I want to search for files in a folder which have a space in its filenames, f.e.

```
/vol1/apache2/application/current/Test 1.pdf
/vol1/apache2/application/current/Test 2.pdf
```

I know there's a find command but I can't figure out the correct parameters to list all those files.

Comment: How about `ls *" "*`? `find . -name "* *"`?

Comment: `echo *" "*` also works

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say: I need the file list for a given folder and all subfolders (recursive search)...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use find command with a space between two wildcards. It will match files with single or multiple spaces. "find ." will find all files in current folder and all the sub-folders. "-type f" will only look for files and not folders.

```
find . -type f -name "* *"
```

**EDIT**

To replace the spaces with underscores, try this

```
find . -type f -name "* *" | while read file; do mv "$file" ${file// /_}; done
```

Comment: And is there also a possibility to rename the results and automatically remove the spaces?

Comment: I think better use `xargs` than `while` in this case.

Comment: This will fail if one parent directory contains spaces in its name

Comment: This is good when parent dir doesn't have spaces

Comment: This is a nice approach. First rename the files and then do the operations

Answer (score 10):

With `find`:

```
find "/vol1/apache2/application/current" -type f -name "*[[:space:]]*"
```

Comment: Nice! Can I add more characters or exclude filename extensions?

Comment: @ssavva05 yeap
Examples:
add characters - `find "/vol1/apache2/application/current" -type f -name "*Test[[:space:]]*.pdf"`

exclude extensions - `find "/vol1/apache2/application/current" -type f -name "*[[:space:]]*" -not -name "*.txt"`

Comment: Great! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me to find all files containing spaces:

```
find ./ -type f | grep " "
```

To also rename all found files to the same filename without the spaces, run the following:

```
find ./ -type f | grep " " | while read file; do mv "$file" ${file// }; done
```

Ways to configure the above script:

- To rename only directories, change `-type f` to `-type d`
- To use git-aware rename, change `do mv` to `do git mv`
- To rename differently, change `${file// };` to `${file// /[some-string]};`. For example, to replace the spaces with "_", use: `${file// /_};` (notice the leading "/")